# Can't create singly linked list

Tags: c, nodes, singly-linked-list

I have an issue creating linked list: I don't know where I do an error in code, could you help me? Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define LENGTH 255

struct node {
    int info;
    struct node *next;
} *head = NULL;

int create(FILE **data){
    char read[LENGTH];
    printf("Write data file name: ");
    scanf("%s", read);
    *data = fopen (read, "r");

    if (data == NULL) {
        printf("Error reading given file.");
    }

    return 0;
}

int put_Symbols_into_list(FILE *data) {

    struct node *new_node, *current;
    char c;

    printf("Data given: ");
    while (!feof(data)){
        new_node = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof (struct node));
        c = fscanf(data, "%s", &new_node -> info);
        printf("%s ", &new_node -> info);

        if (head == NULL){
            head = new_node;
            current = new_node;
        } else {
            current -> next = new_node;
            current = new_node;
        }
    }

}


int main() {
    FILE *data;
    struct node *n;
    create(&data);
    put_Symbols_into_list(data);
    //display_List(n);
    return 0;
}
```

Steps that I do: Read data file for string and put it  new node; if HEAD node doesn't have any data in it, put the read data in it; else put it in new node. Cycle this until there is not data left in data file. You can create new data file and put data in there, like `1 0 1 1 2 3 4 5 6`.

Comment: and where do you face the issue?

Comment: Don't cast `malloc` in C. And have you tried stepping through the program in a debugger?

Comment: You forgot to make the last node point to **NULL** (`new_node->next = NULL`). This will be extremely important when you try to traverse your list and display it.

Comment: A linked-list question with no aparrent debugging.  Quelle surprise.

Comment: I'm assuming I've done something bad, because the list print's out badly when I use another function. Thank you for that NULL though. I don't know about 'malloc', but we use it university. And what do I use to debugg C code?

Comment: Whatever debugger you have available, (gdb?), or struggle with printf() calls.

Comment: Code::Blocks uses GDB/CDB. Well, after writing Assembly code and using it's debugger, I'd really like to see step by step run of program :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not putting `current->next` to NULL after adding a new node. That will make a problem when you try to go through a list, since you won't know where it ends. I hope that's the problem that you're facing with.

Also you're having redundant code, since `current` will always point to `new_node` after adding it. So you don't have to put it both in if and else block. Just an advice.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to make the last node point to **NULL**. This will be extremely important when you try to traverse your list and display it.

```
int put_Symbols_into_list(FILE *data) 
{
    struct node *new_node, *current;
    char c;

    printf("Data given: ");
    while (!feof(data)){
        new_node = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof (struct node));
        c = fscanf(data, "%d", &new_node -> info);
        printf("%d ", new_node->info);

        if (head == NULL){
            head = new_node;
            current = new_node;
        } else {
            current->next = new_node;
            current = new_node;
            new_node->next = NULL;      // << added
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answers above, you are declaring `current` as a local variable in `put_Symbols_into_list`, and not initializing `current`. Each time you exit `put_Symbols_into_list`, the value of `current` may be lost. You either need to declare `current` as `static struct node *current`, pass it as a parameter, or declare it globally. I would favor the static approach in this setting.

Comment: Anyway, now I'm completely lost in linked list C logic. If I'll manage to get everything in position, I hope all of these comment help me. Thank you.